# Getting error on ML-Engine predict but local predict works fine

Tags: tensorflow, google-prediction

I have searched a lot here but unfortunately could not find an answer.

I am running `TensorFlow 1.3` (installed via PiP on MacOS) on my local machine, and have created a model using the [provided](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md) "`ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco`" checkpoints.

I managed to train locally and on the ML-Engine (Runtime 1.2), and successfully deployed my savedModel to the ML-Engine.

Local predictions (below code) work fine and I get the model results

```
gcloud ml-engine local predict --model-dir=... --json-instances=request.json

 FILE request.json: {"inputs": [[[242, 240, 239], [242, 240, 239], [242, 240, 239], [242, 240, 239], [242, 240, 23]]]}
```

However when deploying the model and trying to run on the ML-ENGINE for remote predictions with the code below:

```
gcloud ml-engine predict --model "testModel" --json-instances request.json(SAME JSON FILE AS BEFORE)
```

I get this error:

```
{
  "error": "Prediction failed: Exception during model execution: AbortionError(code=StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT, details=\"NodeDef mentions attr 'data_format' not in Op<name=DepthwiseConv2dNative; signature=input:T, filter:T -> output:T; attr=T:type,allowed=[DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE]; attr=strides:list(int); attr=padding:string,allowed=[\"SAME\", \"VALID\"]>; NodeDef: FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_1_depthwise/depthwise = DepthwiseConv2dNative[T=DT_FLOAT, _output_shapes=[[-1,150,150,32]], data_format=\"NHWC\", padding=\"SAME\", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], _device=\"/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0\"](FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/Relu6, FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_1_depthwise/depthwise_weights/read)\n\t [[Node: FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_1_depthwise/depthwise = DepthwiseConv2dNative[T=DT_FLOAT, _output_shapes=[[-1,150,150,32]], data_format=\"NHWC\", padding=\"SAME\", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], _device=\"/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0\"](FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/Relu6, FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_1_depthwise/depthwise_weights/read)]]\")"
}
```

I saw something similar here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1581

About the problem being with the "data-format" parameter.
But unfortunately I could not use that solution since I am already on TensorFlow 1.3.

It also seems that it might be a problem with MobilenetV1: https:// github.com/ tensorflow/models/issues/2153

Any ideas?

Comment: How did you train locally and successfully deployed your savedModel to the ML-Engine? This seem to imply that you used the TensorFlow 1.3 for training, and then version 1.2 for predictions.

Comment: Hi George! Thank you for the comment!

I have indeed used TF1.3 for training and maybe that is the case. But how can I be using 1.2 for predictions? Can I set that on the gcloud tool or in the web interface???

Comment: You may use version 1.2 of TF locally, for model training purposes, in place of the current TF1.3.

Comment: Thanks again for the comments George!

In the end my team and I have decided to use Tensorflow Serving in a dedicated server to serve the predictions. Working well so far with the same models that were bugging on the ML-Engine.

But I hope someone with similar problems can find this thread and try your suggestion out.

I was also rather disappointed on how difficult was to get support from Google's side for this (through GCP) =(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46889203/7665986). This issue is due to mismatch in Tensorflow versions used for training and inference. I solved the issue by using Tensorflow - 1.4 for both training and inference.

Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47493624/7665986) answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! For the project I am working on we have decided to not use GCP-ML because of this, but I will definitely check it out.

Since I believe your answer should fix this I will mark as solved. I'm glad the TF team worked this out =D

Comment: Is this issue resolved in Tensorflow 1.9 version? I tried to do prediction in CloudML still I got the same error.

Answer (score 2):

If you're wondering how to ensure that your model version is running the correct tensorflow version that you need to run, first have a look at this [model versions list page](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/runtime-version-list)

You need to know which model version supports the Tensorflow version that you need. At the time of writing:

- ML version 1.4 supports TensorFlow 1.4.0 and 1.4.1
- ML version 1.2 supports TensorFlow 1.2.0 and
- ML version 1.0 supports TensorFlow 1.0.1

Now that you know which model version you require, you need to create a new version from your model, like so:

```
gcloud ml-engine versions create <version name> \
--model=<Name of the model> \
--origin=<Model bucket link. It starts with gs://...> \
--runtime-version=1.4
```

In my case, I needed to predict using Tensorflow 1.4.1, so I used the runtime version 1.4.

Refer to this [official MNIST tutorial page](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/running-distributed-tensorflow-on-compute-engine#publishing_your_model_for_predictions), as well as this [ML Versioning Page](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/versioning#to_specify_the_runtime_version_for_a_model_version)