# TensorFlowInferenceInterface: Mobilenet for imagenet : java.io.IOException: Not a valid TensorFlow Graph serialization

Tags: android, tensorflow

I am trying to run mobilenet model trained over imagenet on Android Tensorflow for object recognition and facing the issue as described below.

```
 TensorFlowInferenceInterface: Failed to load model 
    from 'file:///android_asset/mobilenet_imagenet.pb': java.io.IOException: 
    Not a valid TensorFlow Graph serialization: 
    NodeDef mentions attr 'data_format' not in Op<name=DepthwiseConv2dNative;
    signature=input:T, filter:T -> output:T; 
    attr=T:type,allowed=[DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE]; attr=strides:list(int); 
    attr=padding:string,allowed=["SAME", "VALID"]>; 
    NodeDef: conv_dw_1/depthwise = 
DepthwiseConv2dNative[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", padding="SAME", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1]]
    (conv1_relu/clip_by_value, conv_dw_1/depthwise_kernel/read)
```

I followed the tutorial as given in the [link](https://blog.mindorks.com/android-tensorflow-machine-learning-example-ff0e9b2654cc) to integrate Tensorflow on Android. I could run basic CNN classifier custom trained (using python 2.7.12, Tensorflow 1.2 on Ubuntu 16.04)and it is working fine.

I could successfully run Mobilenet trained over imagenet on python 2.7.12 on Ubuntu 16.04 using Tensorflow 1.2 and 1.3. Now when I try to run the same '.pb' model on Android it gives me the error as mentioned above.

The code for initializing the model is as given below :

```
TensorFlowImageClassifier c = new TensorFlowImageClassifier();
c.inferenceInterface = new TensorFlowInferenceInterface();
if (c.inferenceInterface.initializeTensorFlow(assetManager, modelFilename) != 0) {
         throw new RuntimeException("TF initialization failed");
}
```

Please provide me a solution or a work around

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The above issue has been resolved by updating the "libandroid_tensorflow_inference_java.jar" and "libtensorflow_inference.so" to the latest version i.e. Tensorflow - 1.4. The latest ".jar" and ".so" files can be found [here](https://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/job/nightly-android/).

The issue was due to mismatch of Tensorflow versions. Mobilenet classifier trained over ImageNet was built on Tensorflow - 1.3 and was being used for inference on Android with Tensorflow - 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

It says here in main activity java file

```
private static final String MODEL_FILE = "file:///android_asset/expert-graph.pb";
private static final String LABEL_FILE = "file:///android_asset/labels.txt";
```

Where your model files seems to be "mobilenet_imagenet.pb". After you make sure your model and labels name match for the project file here, change the input size what you trained on.(retrain.py file maybe has this information.)

```
private static final int INPUT_SIZE = 160;//
private static final int IMAGE_MEAN = 128;
private static final float IMAGE_STD = 128;
private static final String OUTPUT_NAME = "final_result";
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. 
I have already initialized the variables as you have suggested. But the error occurs while it executes this.load((InputStream)var4); inside c.inferenceInterface.initializeTensorFlow(assetManager, modelFilename)